# Base64 image screenshot in extent report is showing garbage value on clicking the screenshot in the report

Tags: java, selenium, base64, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Base64 image in selenium extent report is not displayed correctly after clicking the image in the report.

Searched various sources to get the issue resolution but did not find the answer anywhere

//dependency in POM.xml Code:-

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
 <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

//ExtentReporterListener Code :-

```
public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " failed!"));
    test.get().fail("Test failed due to below error");
    try {
        test.get().fail(result.getThrowable(), MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(TestUtil.getScreenshotExtent()).build());
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.
        println("Exception thrown while updating test fail status " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
    }
    test.get().getModel().setEndTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));
}
```

//Capture screenshots code:-

```
public class TestUtil {
    public static String getScreenshotExtent() {
        String Base64StringofScreenshot = "";
        File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        byte[] fileContent;
        try {
            fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(src);
            Base64StringofScreenshot = "data:image/png;base64," + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Base64StringofScreenshot;
    }
}
```

[image]

Can someone please help how to resolve this issue and correctly display the image in extent report after clicking it?

Answer (score 0):

can you please let me know in which browser you are running this Automation suite?

for e.g: You are using Chrome browser in windows OS 64 bit, then you need to check the chromedriver.exe which you have downloaded, that is for 32 bit or 64 bit.If you are using the driver for 32 bit then this type of issue comes.

If you are still not finding any solution then let me know.

Comment: I have windows OS 64 bit, but i think there is only 1 chromedriver.exe that support both 32 bit and 64 bit OS. I am using the latest version of chromedriver.exe as it supports my current chrome browser. Is there any other way to resolve the issue?